# Elements of numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy, element

There are 500 rows and 5 columns in a csv fle called testdata.csv

the code below returns all 5 columns of row 1 like this
( 5907364.237, -447070.8817,  293.339355, 2193094)
or I can get row 50 using  MyValue = csv[49]
( 5906798.994, -447499.987,  373.128906, 2194385)

BUT I can't seem to work out how to return the value of row 50, column 3 on it's own

```
import numpy as np
def walk(MyFile):
    csv = np.genfromtxt(MyFile, delimiter=',',dtype=(None))
    MyValue = csv[0]
    return MyValue

MyValue=walk('testdata.csv')    
print(MyValue)
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to read a basic `numpy` introduction, where you'll learn about array shapes and indexing.  For example, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

csv[49][2] doesn't do the trick?

You might consider [pandas dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html).

Comment: The  proper way to index in an element of a 2d array is `csr[49, 2]`.  Why would `pandas` be any easier?  It is built on top of `numpy`.

Comment: I've found `pandas.read_csv` to be much more robust than `numpy.genfromtxt` but both will definitely work

Comment: Yes, the pandas reader is faster, and handles more cases.  But I don't think the OP is having problems reading the file.  It's more a question of interpreting the resulting array.

Comment: @CharlieD if that did the trick, please mark as answered to close the question!